# 401 when calling Teams Bot deployed in Azure

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, teams-toolkit

I've created a Notification Bot in VS Code using the Teams Toolkit template (Teams Toolkit v4.1.2).

The Bot runs fine locally and I'm able to trigger it by sending a `HTTP Post` request from Postman.

It deploys fine to Azure, but when I call it from Postman (using the url from the Azure App Service), I get a `401 Unauthorized` response.

I've followed the [Troubleshooting Bot Framework authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) guide to generate an access token from my bot's App Id & App Password using the following command:

`curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default"`

This generates an access token, but when I add that to the header of my Postman request I get a `403 Forbidden` response.

How do I trigger my bot in Azure from an HTTP Post request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several APIs for a Notification Bot, and please make sure you are sending POST to '**/api/notification**', e.g.,

POST to *https://{your-azure-host}.azurewebsites.net/**api/notification***

In addition, the `401 Unauthorized` may be returned by another API **/api/messages** which is used for Bot Framework Connection. If you are manually calling */api/messages*, you may need to go through the access token flow with Bot ID and Password.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the App registration you have added the required api permissions or not 403 means you didn't provided the required api permissions in the app registration